# 3D view of a route shown on a map

Tags: graphics3d, visualization

You should have already seen such a thing, specially in documentaries about ancient life: the movement of a tribe is shown on an ancient map along a route with a dashed arrow. I want to do the same thing in Mathematica.

Given a bitmap image of a map [like this one](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/China_old_map.jpg) and a list of points on the 2d map such as `{{123,233}, {177, 279}, ...}`, I want to make a movie that shows an arrow along the given route on the map. The movie looks like it is captured from a helicopter flying on the map.

*Edit:*

This is what I did after `rm -rf♦`'s comment:

```
map = ImageResize[
   Import["http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/China_\
old_map.jpg"], 500];
path = .3 {{300, 500}, {350, 600}, {450, 700}, {600, 750}, {650, 
     750}, {700, 780}, {800, 800}, {850, 900}, {900, 1000}, {1000, 
     1050}, {1100, 1050}, {1150, 1100}};
ListAnimate[
 Table[Show[map, Graphics[{Thick, Dashed, Arrow[Take[path, i]]}], 
   ImageSize -> {500}], {i, Length@path}]]
```

Comment: This shouldn't be very hard to do. Using `Line` or `Arrow` to draw the primitives, update the list of points to add a new point as time progresses. This gives you the list of frames for the movie. You can then use `ListAnimate` or `Export` as a gif or a movie. If you want a close up view from the top and move along the map as the direction changes, use `ImageTake` to focus on only a WxH rectangle centered at the latest point. I suggest that you make an attempt first and show us what you've tried.

Comment: What you described is just fine for a flat 2d view. But I am looking for a 3d view, that is, the camera is not perpendicular to the map.

Comment: I think you will find many tools you need in @Vitaly's notebook [Mastering Dynamic Visualizations](http://www.wolfram.com/events/virtual-conference/2012/resources.html) and the related [video](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?channel=299&video=1330). To map your 2D picture to a plane in 3D `Texture` may be the right tool (see [this Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13661/125) for an example.)

Comment: More in the cineastic sense, this is kind of reminiscent of Indiana Jones travel scenes :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
map = Import["http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/China_old_map.jpg"]
{w, h} = map // ImageDimensions;
```

The route:

```
route = {{1107.07`, 184.181`}, {1096.17`, 198.195`}, {1072.81`, 237.121`}, {1071.25`, 244.906`}, {1068.14`, 254.249`}, {1065.03`, 265.148`}, {1063.47`, 274.49`}, {1063.47`, 286.947`}, {1063.47`, 296.289`}, {1063.47`, 308.746`}, {1061.91`, 313.417`}, {1061.91`,  319.645`}, {1057.24`, 338.33`}, {1051.01`, 350.786`}, {1044.78`, 361.685`}, {1037.`, 372.585`}, {1029.21`, 381.927`}, {1019.87`, 388.155`}, {1012.09`, 391.269`}, {1001.19`, 397.498`}, {991.845`, 403.726`}, {980.945`, 409.954`}, {970.046`, 413.068`}, {957.589`,   417.739`}, {943.576`, 425.525`}, {935.791`, 430.196`}, {931.119`, 433.31`}, {924.891`, 437.981`}, {921.777`, 441.095`}, {918.663`, 448.881`}, {915.549`, 451.995`}, {907.764`, 462.894`}, {903.092`, 470.679`}, {899.978`, 481.579`}, {895.307`, 489.364`}, {893.75`,  497.149`}, {892.193`, 504.935`}, {887.522`, 511.163`}, {884.408`, 517.391`}, {882.851`, 525.176`}, {881.294`, 539.19`}, {879.737`,  545.418`}, {878.18`, 550.089`}, {876.622`, 556.317`}, {876.622`, 567.217`}, {876.622`, 578.116`}, {876.622`, 587.459`}, {876.622`, 598.358`}, {876.622`, 603.029`}, {870.394`, 618.6`}, {868.837`, 629.499`}, {862.609`, 643.513`}, {857.938`, 657.526`}, {853.267`, 668.425`}, {848.595`, 680.882`}, {840.81`, 690.224`}, {833.025`, 699.567`}, {825.24`, 707.352`}, {819.011`, 715.137`}, {811.226`, 721.365`}, {800.327`, 729.151`}, {787.87`, 738.493`}, {781.642`, 746.278`}, {775.414`, 752.506`}, {772.3`, 752.506`}, {761.4`, 763.406`}, {744.273`, 783.648`}, {734.93`, 794.547`}, {725.588`, 813.232`}, {714.689`, 830.359`}, {708.46`, 844.373`}, {703.789`, 861.5`}, {700.675`, 873.957`}, {699.118`, 884.856`}, {699.118`, 900.427`}, {700.675`, 911.326`}, {702.232`, 920.669`}, {708.46`, 928.454`}, {720.917`, 940.91`}, {730.259`, 948.696`}, {739.602`, 954.924`}, {759.843`, 965.823`}, {781.642`, 975.165`}, {800.327`, 978.28`}, {815.897`, 979.837`}, {819.011`, 979.837`}, {834.582`, 981.394`}, {853.267`, 984.508`}, {868.837`, 986.065`}, {879.737`, 986.065`}, {890.636`, 987.622`}, {898.421`, 987.622`}, {912.435`, 989.179`}, {923.334`, 990.736`}, {932.677`, 992.293`}, {943.576`, 993.85`}, {954.475`, 995.407`}, {968.489`, 995.407`}, {977.831`, 996.964`}, {987.173`, 998.521`}, {996.516`, 1000.08`}, {1007.42`, 1001.64`}, {1019.87`, 1004.75`}, {1027.66`, 1004.75`}, {1033.89`, 1006.31`}, {1044.78`, 1007.86`}, {1058.8`, 1009.42`}, {1068.14`, 1009.42`}, {1072.81`, 1009.42`}, {1102.4`, 1006.31`}, {1121.08`, 1003.19`}, {1144.44`, 998.521`}, {1156.89`, 996.964`}, {1175.58`, 992.293`}, {1194.26`, 982.951`}, {1206.72`, 978.28`}, {1222.29`, 972.051`}, {1244.09`, 962.709`}, {1258.1`, 958.038`}, {1262.77`, 956.481`}, {1292.36`, 942.467`}, {1326.61`, 933.125`}, {1349.97`, 925.34`}, {1363.98`, 919.111`}, {1370.21`, 917.554`}, {1373.32`, 915.997`}, {1379.55`, 911.326`}, {1384.22`, 908.212`}, {1387.34`, 906.655`}, {1390.45`, 906.655`}, {1395.12`, 901.984`}, {1401.35`, 898.87`}, {1407.58`, 895.756`}, {1410.69`, 894.199`}, {1413.81`, 889.527`}, {1418.48`, 884.856`}, {1421.59`, 883.299`}, {1423.15`, 880.185`}, {1426.26`, 877.071`}, {1430.93`, 872.4`}, {1432.49`, 869.286`}, {1432.49`, 864.614`}, {1435.61`, 858.386`}};
```

Use `ImageCompose`to combine route and map:

```
Manipulate[
 ImageCompose[
   map, 
   Graphics[{Thickness[0.02], Dashed, Arrowheads[.06], Arrow[SplineCurve@Take[route, i]]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, w}, {0, h}}]
 ], {i, 1, Length@route, 1}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Routines to show a part of the route:

```
routePart[i_] := Take[route, Max[1, Round[Length[route] i]]]
mapPlusRoute[i_] := 
 ImageCompose[map, 
  Graphics[{Thickness[0.02], Dashed, Arrowheads[.06], 
    Arrow[BSplineCurve@routePart[i]]}, PlotRange -> {{0, w}, {0, h}}]]
```

Now put it in 3D using `Graphics3D` and `Texture`. Add some camera movements and aiming and... presto. I exported the separate frames to process them in an external program, but MMA can make animated GIFs as well.

```
mc = 1;
Do[
 Export["C:\\Users\\Sjoerd\\Desktop\\Movie\\Movie" <> 
   IntegerString[mc++, 10, 4] <> ".bmp",
  Graphics3D[
   {
    Texture[mapPlusRoute[i]], 
    Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {w, 0, 0}, {w, h, 0}, {0, h, 0}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]
    },
   Lighting -> "Neutral",
   Boxed -> False,
   ViewVector -> {{1500 Cos[i 2 \[Pi] ] + w/2, 
      h/2 - 1500 Sin[2 \[Pi] i ], 1000}, 
     Append[routePart[i][[-1]], 0]},
   ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1},
   ViewAngle -> 25 \[Degree], ImageSize -> 600
   ]
  ],
 {i, 0.07, 1, .005}
 ]
```

[Gif Movie here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3675222/movie2.gif), uploading didn't work at the moment. The hand-drawn route is a bit rocky but you get the idea.

Comment: +1 for the effort, but that GIF has a kind of judder that makes me feel a bit ill after watching it.  Do you know of any way to improve that?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The route point set is a bit rough (it was hand drawn, as I wrote above) so the orientation of the arrow isn't very stable (the camera's orientation is dependent on the arrow position as well, so an erratic arrow path doesn't help there either). I just saw that after making the movie, and didn't want to do it all over again. It's the principle that counts, after all.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Could you try including the GIF in the text itself? When I try to do that, my connection is throttled to a few bytes/sec. Never had that before.

Comment: The file is 17.5 MB -- probably too large for Imgur.

Answer (score 14):

Here's your approach, but with 3D primitives. You can then move the camera around using your own definition for `ViewVector` (or you can steal Sjoerd's):

```
Module[{mapZ = 0, mapDim = ImageDimensions@map, arrowZ = 5, ordering},
    Graphics3D[
        {
            {Texture@map,Polygon[
                List[##, mapZ] & @@@ Tuples[Transpose@{{0, 0}, mapDim}] // 
                    #[[ordering = Rest@First@FindCurvePath@#]] &,
                VertexTextureCoordinates -> Tuples[{0, 1}, 2][[ordering]]
            ]},
            {Red, Thick, Tube[List[##, arrowZ] & @@@ path]}
        },
        Lighting -> "Neutral",Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/100}
    ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Why is it not working properly on my computer?

Comment: I don't know...

Comment: @yulinlinyu Perhaps you're on version 7 which doesn't have Texture or your graphics card doesn't support it or ... or...

Comment: @ Sjoerd C. de Vries, it is mathematica 8. No path is displayed on the graph in my computer.

Comment: @yulinlinyu Maybe the default view in yours is different. Try flipping the map upside down...

Answer (score 3):

Using some `Graphics3D` construct and changing `ViewVector` option might do for a good start

```
map=Import["http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/\
China_old_map.jpg"];

(* Destinations, taken by right clicking image extracting coordinates \
with Get Coordinates *)

destinations = {{1758.32`, 1251.75`}, {877.471`, 509.279`}, {600.73`, 
    802.894`}, {948.343`, 910.891`}, {1076.59`, 617.276`}, {1181.21`, 
    1143.76`}, {1434.33`, 667.899`}, {1464.7`, 904.141`}};

(* Height of helicopter *)
height = 500;

{w, h} = ImageDimensions[map];

(* Interpolate flight path *)
path = Interpolation[MapIndexed[{First[#2], #1} &, destinations]];

(* Polygon with map as texture *)
world = Graphics3D[{
    Texture[map], EdgeForm[Black], 
    Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {w, 0, 0}, {w, h, 0}, {0, h, 0}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}];

DynamicModule[{t = 1.1},
 Column[
  {Slider[Dynamic[t], {1, Length[destinations]}],
   Dynamic[t],
   Show[
    world,
    Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[15], 
      Arrow[Dynamic[{Append[path[t - 0.1], 1], Append[path[t], 1]}]]}],
    (* View from height units above path straight down, the 0.0001 is just there to avoid weird rotations *)
    ViewVector -> 
     Dynamic[{Append[path[t], height], 
       Append[path[t], 0] + {0.0001, 0, 0}}]]}]]
```