# How to produce a chasing-view in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics3d

I would like to chase the flying plane with a video camera, how to do that in Mathematica?

[image]

```
R = 20 ;
pR = 30;
oR = 40 ;
highRng = {20 , 50 };
t = 0;
posts = Table[{Hue[RandomReal[]], 
    Cylinder[{{R Cos[ang], R Sin[ang], 0}, {R Cos[ang], R Sin[ang], 
       RandomInteger[highRng]}}]}, {ang, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/12}];

oposts = Table[{Hue[RandomReal[]], 
    Cylinder[{{oR Cos[ang], oR Sin[ang], 0}, {oR Cos[ang], 
       oR Sin[ang], RandomInteger[highRng]}}]}, {ang, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/12}];

(*********          link for the plane obj file:          ********)
(*  https://www.dropbox.com/s/7knvl519hg3s6qp/plane-4.obj?dl=0   *)

im = Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/7knvl519hg3s6qp/plane-4.obj?dl=1"][[1]];

Dynamic[
 Refresh[
  t = t + 0.1 ;
   Graphics3D[{posts, oposts, White,
    Translate[
     Rotate[im, t, {0, 0, 1}], {pR Cos[t], pR Sin[ t ], 20 + Sin[t]}]
    } , PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 50}},
   Background -> Black, Boxed -> False
     ] ,
  UpdateInterval -> 0.1 ] ,
 TrackedSymbols -> {}
 ]
```

Comment: Related: [(3528)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3528), [(5649)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5649)

Comment: And perhaps [14480](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14480)

Comment: I guess a first step would be finding the tangential vector with respect to the motion and using it as "ViewPoint" in the Graphics3D. [Tangent vector](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TangentVector.html)

Comment: Since you are moving in a circle you could of course use the the angular unit vector of your polar coordinates.

Comment: See also: Slide 7 in Vitaly Kaurov's [Mastering Dynamic Visualizations](http://www.wolfram.com/training/special-event/wolfram-visualization-virtual-workshop-2013/)

Comment: `pos2 = RotationMatrix[#, {0, 0, 1}].(1.1 {-0.00465, -1.6416, 0.64730}) + {pR Cos[#], pR Sin[#], 20 + Sin[#]} &` and use it in options for graphics `ViewVector -> {pos2[t - 1], 
  pos2[t + .1]}, ViewAngle -> 1`

Answer (score 3):

```
R = 20; pR = 30; oR = 40; highRng = {20, 50}; t = 0;
posts = Table[{Hue[RandomReal[]], 
    Cylinder[{{R Cos[ang], R Sin[ang], 0}, {R Cos[ang], R Sin[ang], 
    RandomInteger[highRng]}}]}, {ang, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/12}];
oposts = Table[{Hue[RandomReal[]], Cylinder[{{oR Cos[ang], oR Sin[ang], 0}, {oR Cos[ang], 
    oR Sin[ang], RandomInteger[highRng]}}]}, {ang, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/12}];
im = Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/7knvl519hg3s6qp/plane-4.obj?dl=1"][[1]];

viewvector[t_] = 
  TranslationTransform[{pR Cos[t], pR Sin[t], 20 + Sin[t]}]@
   (RotationTransform[t, {0, 0, 1}][{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 20, 0}}]);
pic1[t_] := 
  Graphics3D[{posts, oposts, White, 
    Translate[Rotate[im, t, {0, 0, 1}], {pR Cos[t], pR Sin[t], 20 + Sin[t]}]}, 
    PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 50}}, Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 200];
pic2[t_] := 
  Graphics3D[{posts, oposts, White}, PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 50}},
    Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, ViewVector -> viewvector[t]];
Manipulate[{pic1[t], pic2[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: The assignment of `viewvector[t]` should be `:=`.

Comment: @evanb It is also correct that use Set.

Answer (score 2):

Following the suggestions from the nice guys here, I finally figured out how to get the game started:

```
R = 20; pR = 30; oR = 40; highRng = {20, 50}; t = 0;
posts = Table[{Hue[RandomReal[]], 
    Cylinder[{{R Cos[ang], R Sin[ang], 0}, {R Cos[ang], R Sin[ang], 
       RandomInteger[highRng]}}]}, {ang, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/12}];

oposts = Table[{Hue[RandomReal[]], 
    Cylinder[{{oR Cos[ang], oR Sin[ang], 0}, {oR Cos[ang], 
       oR Sin[ang], RandomInteger[highRng]}}]}, {ang, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/12}];

im = Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/7knvl519hg3s6qp/plane-4.obj?dl=1"][[1]];


Dynamic[Refresh[t = t + 0.1;
  Graphics3D[{posts, oposts, White, 
    Translate[
     Rotate[im, t, {0, 0, 1}], {pR Cos[t], pR Sin[t], 20 + Sin[t]}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 50}},
   Background -> Black,
   Boxed -> False,
   ViewVector -> { 
     BlockRandom[{pR Cos[t - RandomReal[{0.5, 0.9}]], 
       pR Sin[t - RandomReal[{0.5, 0.9}]] , 
       80 RandomReal[{0.1, 1}]}], {pR Cos[t], pR Sin[t], 20 + Sin[t]}} 
   ],
  UpdateInterval -> 0.1],
 TrackedSymbols -> {}
 ]
```

[image]