# Plotting a contour line in 2d on a 3d surface

Tags: plotting

I have a list of data which I can plot as a surface with `ListPlot3D`. Moreover I have a set of other surfaces and I have plotted the projection of their intersection curves onto a plane via `ContourPlot`.
Is there a way of plotting on the surface originating from `ListPlot3D` above the curve originating from the `ContourPlot`?

Comment: see maybe this [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67048/showing-contours-on-top-of-a-listplot3d) (23 hours ago !)

Comment: Thank you! But I have not a function creating a contour plot

Comment: related [Using a ListDensityPlot to map color onto a ListPlot3D graph](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13661/125)

Comment: I'd also recommend having a look for any question referencing `MeshFunctions`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Few more alternatives:

```
data = Table[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi, .2}, {y, 0, 4 Pi, .2}];
```

**Using a combination of `Mesh`, `MeshFunctions`, `MeshShading`:**

```
ListPlot3D[data, DataRange -> {{0, 4 Pi}, {0, 4 Pi}}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #1 &, #2 &}, 
 Mesh -> {5, 10, 10}, MeshStyle -> {None, Automatic, Automatic}, 
 MeshShading -> {{Directive[{EdgeForm[], #}] & /@ {Red, Green, Blue,Orange, Magenta, Cyan}}}]
```

[image]

**Using `Texture`:**

```
cp = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
   Contours -> 5, ContourStyle -> None, 
   ContourShading -> {Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Magenta, Cyan}, 
   ImagePadding -> 0, PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> False, Axes -> False];

ListPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> Texture[cp],  DataRange -> {{0, 4 Pi}, {0, 4 Pi}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

One solution is to transform your 2d contour plot into 3d coordinates. For this, you have to look at the underlying representation of the `Graphics` that `ContourPlot` creates. This is usually a `Graphics[GraphicsComplex[coords,...],...]` object, where `coords` are the coordinates of the points used.

Let us create simple example data and plot them

```
data = Table[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi, .2}, {y, 0, 4 Pi, .2}];
lp = ListPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> None, DataRange -> {{0, 4 Pi}, {0, 4 Pi}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And here is a possible contour plot that you want to lift onto the surface of the 3d plot

```
cp = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, your task would be to replace the 2d coordinates with their 3d counterpart and replace `Graphics` with `Graphics3D`. Then, you can easily put your `ListPlot3D` and the `ContourPlot` together. For this, I suggest to interpolate the data so that you can extract the height of the surface of each point.

```
ip = ListInterpolation[data, {{0, 4 Pi}, {0, 4 Pi}}];
in3D = cp /.
  Graphics[GraphicsComplex[coords_, rest__], ___] :> 
  Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[Append[#, ip @@ #] & /@ coords, rest]]
```

To say in words what happens above: I replace every 2d coordinate of the contour plot with a 3d coordinate, where the z value is extracted from the interpolation of your data.

[image: in3d]

Now you are done and you can combine the two 3d graphics

```
Show[in3D, lp]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Pugliam Oh well, I have misunderstood the line *plotting on the surface originating from ListPlot3D above the curve*.. For your questions does exist an answer too. I would interpolate your data-set and use the hight-values at x,y for the height of your curve.. let's see whether I can code this up in a sec

Comment: Thank you! But maybe I haven't been clear enough in asking what I need ;)
I do not want to plot, in the same graph, a surface and its contours lines on the plane. I'd like to plot the contour lines on the surface itself. Moreover I need to plot curves which are not contour lines of the same surface but they are given by the intersection of other surfaces I do not care at the moment.

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I have just seen you reply

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the set of data I have is pretty weird and I think ListInterpolation gets stuck (I tried plotting the Interpolating Function and it didn't resemble at all the original set of data, but maybe I'm simply making some mistakes I don't know). Anyhow may you kindly post again the previous solution: surface plot on the same graph as contiurlines? Thanks

Comment: @haluritan I'm sorry asking again but would you mind posting what you suggested at the beginning, i.e. how to make a 3d plot with the surface and the 2d contourplot embedded into the 3d graphic?

Comment: @Pugliam You don't need me for this. Under my answer you should see a link "edited yesterday". When you click on this, you see the whole history of the post.