# Mapping Contour Plot onto ListPlot3D (or by using color variations)

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, plotting

I am trying to overlay a contour plot I have created on a `ListPlot3D` graph.  I have seen a few questions answered on this website that answer my basic question.  However, the contour plot I need to use cannot be simply applied to a table, so the `ListInterpolation` function is not of use to me.  Is there a way to get around this problem?  Right now, I have used a method provided in this question, [Using a ListDensityPlot to map color onto a ListPlot3D graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13661/using-a-listdensityplot-to-map-color-onto-a-listplot3d-graph) (using an image rather than the actual function to graph) but the resulting graphic (`cp5`) is slighly blurry, not oriented correctly, and not to the perfect size (see the function below).

```
ListPlot3D[gs5Matrix5, TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &), 
 PlotStyle -> Texture[cp5], PlotRange -> All, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, Mesh -> None, ImagePadding -> None]
```

In addition, `gs5Matrix` gives an array of coordinates (i.e. `{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {..}...}`.  I found this to be the easiest way to represent the points seeing as the second coordinate spacing (which has to do with unevenly spaced cosine values) makes it difficult to show in a table.

The contour function is as follows:

```
potentialM5[r_, θ_] :=
 Module[{x, n, ϵ, V},
  x = r/Rm5[θ, κ] /. m5values;
  n = m5[θ, ξ] + γ*(x - 1) /. m5values;
  ϵ = ϵ0 + dϵ1*f[θ, λ] + dϵ2*g[θ] /. m5values;
  V = ϵ/(n - 6)*(6*x^-n - n*x^-6);
  V
  ]

cp5 = ContourPlot[
  potentialM5[r, θ], {θ, 0, 180}, {r, 3, 6}, 
  Contours -> contours]

Rm5[θ_, v_] = Rm0 + dR1*f[θ, v] + dR2*g[θ];
g[θ_] = If[θ >= 90, Cos[(θ*π)/180]^2, 0];
m5[θ_, v_] = m0 + dm*f[θ, v];
m5values = {ϵ0 -> 180.51, dϵ1 -> -79.35, 
dϵ2 -> 34.0, λ -> 4.04, Rm0 -> 4.0093, 
dR1 -> -.1234, dR2 -> -.160, κ -> 12.11, m0 -> 22.39, 
dm -> -9.93, ξ -> 17.25, γ -> 9.0};
f[θ_, v_] = 1 - (1/2 (1 + Cos[(θ*π)/180]))^v;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:  Since my `g5Matrix5` is too challenging to define here, I have devised a simpler example whose answer should provide me with an answer to my own question.  Below are the equations for both the contour plot as well as the ListPlot3D.

```
 ContourPlot[Sin[x]^2 + 2 y, {x, 0, 2 π}, {y, 0, 4}];

values = {{0, 0, 0.2`}, {0, 1, 0.3`}, {0, 3.5`, 0.43`}, {0, 4, 0.2`},
   {(2 π)/3, 0, 0.38`}, {(2 π)/3, 1, 0.45`}, {(2 π)/3, 3.5`, 0.25`},
   {(2 π)/3, 4, 0.1`}, {(4 π)/3, 0, 0.37`}, {(4 π)/3, 1, 0.4`},
   {(4 π)/3, 3.5`, 0.5`}, {(4 π)/3, 4, 0.2`}, {2 π, 0, 0.2`},
   {2 π, 1, 0.5`}, {2 π, 3.5`, 0.35`}, {2 π, 4, 0.22`}};
```

As you can see, the y-values are spaced unevenly

Comment: A self-contained working example would increase the likelihood of a good answer.  And welcome to Mathematica Stack Exchange. :-)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!  I have added some information about the functions I am using in my original post.  Please let me know if there's anything else that can provide clarity.

Comment: I formatted your code.  However this still isn't a self-contained example as we do not have definitions for `Rm5`, `m5values`, etc.  Is this simplest code that can be used to illustrate your situation?

Comment: The remaining variables should be defined below: m5values = {\[Epsilon]0 -> 180.51, d\[Epsilon]1 -> -79.35, 
   d\[Epsilon]2 -> 34.0, \[Lambda] -> 4.04, Rm0 -> 4.0093, 
   dR1 -> -.1234, dR2 -> -.160, \[Kappa] -> 12.11, m0 -> 22.39, 
   dm -> -9.93, \[Xi] -> 17.25, \[Gamma] -> 9.0};

Rm5[\[Theta]_, v_] = Rm0 + dR1*f[\[Theta], v] + dR2*g[\[Theta]];
g[\[Theta]_] = If[\[Theta] >= 90, Cos[(\[Theta]*\[Pi])/180]^2, 0];
m5[\[Theta]_, v_] = m0 + dm*f[\[Theta], v];
f[\[Theta]_, v_] = 1 - (1/2 (1 + Cos[(\[Theta]*\[Pi])/180]))^v;

Comment: You have not defined `contours` or `gs5Matrix5`. Please make sure that your code can be copied from the question into a fresh *Mathematica* session and produce the plot.

Comment: I have now added information above (see the "Update" section) that provides simplified functions that can be used to explain my problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no one is interested: the question and none of the answers are upvoted, the OP has not visited the site in 10 months -- **obviously** too localized.

Answer (score 3):

You can strip the frame and padding from the contour plot and the OP's approach seems to work.

```
cp5 = ContourPlot[Sin[x]^2 + 2 y, {x, 0, 2 π}, {y, 0, 4}];

values = {{0, 0, 0.2`}, {0, 1, 0.3`}, {0, 3.5`, 0.43`}, {0, 4, 0.2`},
   {(2 π)/3, 0, 0.38`}, {(2 π)/3, 1, 0.45`}, {(2 π)/3, 3.5`, 0.25`},
   {(2 π)/3, 4, 0.1`}, {(4 π)/3, 0, 0.37`}, {(4 π)/3, 1, 0.4`},
   {(4 π)/3, 3.5`, 0.5`}, {(4 π)/3, 4, 0.2`}, {2 π, 0, 0.2`},
   {2 π, 1, 0.5`}, {2 π, 3.5`, 0.35`}, {2 π, 4, 0.22`}};

lpcp5 = ListPlot3D[values, TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &),
  PlotStyle -> 
   Texture[Show[cp5, Frame -> None, PlotRangePadding -> None, ImagePadding -> None]],
  PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, Mesh -> None, 
  ImagePadding -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
GraphicsRow[{
  cp5, Show[lpcp5, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}, ImagePadding -> {{15, 0}, {15, 0}}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

I may have misunderstood but avoiding the overlays (and using `values`:

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[x]^2 + 2 y
mx = Maximize[{f[x, y], 0 < x < 2 Pi, 0 < y < 4}, {x, y}]
mn = Minimize[{f[x, y], 0 < x < 2 Pi, 0 < y < 4}, {x, y}]
cont = Range[0, 9, 1];
contc[col_] := ColorData[col][#/9] & /@ cont;
Manipulate[
 ListPlot3D[values, MeshFunctions -> {Sin[#1]^2 + 2 #2 &}, 
  Mesh -> {cont}, MeshShading -> contc[color]], {color, 
  ColorData["Gradients"]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I drew a contour plot by defining Contours as 5,If it looks something like what your are
 expecting we may be on the right track.However I can't do the List Plot because 
 gs5Matrix5 is not defined.

```
Rm5[θ_, v_] = Rm0 + dR1*f[θ, v] + dR2*g[θ];

g[θ_] = If[θ >= 90, Cos[(θ*π)/180]^2, 0];
m5[θ_, v_] = m0 + dm*f[θ, v];
m5values = {ϵ0 -> 180.51, dϵ1 -> -79.35, 
   dϵ2 -> 34.0, λ -> 4.04, Rm0 -> 4.0093, 
   dR1 -> -.1234, dR2 -> -.160, κ -> 12.11, m0 -> 22.39, 
   dm -> -9.93, ξ -> 17.25, γ -> 9.0};
f[θ_, v_] = 1 - (1/2 (1 + Cos[(θ*π)/180]))^v;

potentialM5[r_, θ_] := 
 Module[{x, n, ϵ, V}, 
  x = r/Rm5[θ, κ] /. m5values;
  n = m5[θ, ξ] + γ*(x - 1) /. m5values;
  ϵ = ϵ0 + dϵ1*f[θ, λ] + 
     dϵ2*g[θ] /. m5values;
  V = ϵ/(n - 6)*(6*x^-n - n*x^-6);
  V]

cp5 = ContourPlot[
  potentialM5[r, θ], {θ, 0, 180}, {r, 3, 6}, 
  Contours -> 5]
```

Comment: This helps me with plotting the countour, but I did have this portion of my problem solved.  I am looking for a way to map this contour on top of the ListPlot3D.  I have updated my initial question with a simplified answer that has values for the ListPlot3D as well as the contour.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ListPlot3D[values, MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, Sin[x]^2 + 2 y]}]
```

This produces a pretty low-quality output for the given example, but the more points you have in the `ListPlot` the more points are used in calculating the contours for the mesh.

For example:

```
 ListPlot3D[
  Join @@ Table[{x, y, Abs[Sin[x + I y]]}, {x, -Pi, +Pi, 
     Pi/20.}, {y, -1, +1, 0.05}], 
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, Arg[Sin[x + I y]]]}, 
  BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

(Plotting the absolute value of the complex `Sin` function, and overlaying contours of the complex argument.)

Comment: I just noticed that you specified the contour values with `Contours -> contours`, in this case you can use `Mesh -> {contours}`.