# Create a color coded ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting, color

I currently have a plot that I want to display in the format of ListPlot3D (as in some continuous 2D contour embedded in 3D), but the key is that I'd like to preserve this color coding I have.

I am basically quantifying some variable of a system (svet on the z-axis) as a function of two varying parameters (b and $\gamma$ on the x and y axis respectively). Each time I quantify this variable, svet, I try 3 different methods and color code the output based on which method gave me the maximal value. Then I append each output to its own array and plot each of the 3 arrays separately to manually color code them.

Is there a way I can preserve this coloring and switch this to a ListPlot3D?

Here is the code:

```
(*basically a package for more convenient commands*)
Get["http://www.fmt.if.usp.br/~gtlandi/download/melt.m"]
LoadPauliMatrices[];

(*3 different methods to quantify svet*)
r1[\[Theta]_] := Cos[\[Theta]]*\[Sigma]x + Sin[\[Theta]]*\[Sigma]y;
r2[\[Theta]_] := Cos[\[Theta]]*\[Sigma]x + Sin[\[Theta]]*\[Sigma]z;
r3[\[Theta]_] := Cos[\[Theta]]*\[Sigma]z + Sin[\[Theta]]*\[Sigma]y;
rot1[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := kron[r1[\[Theta]], r1[\[Phi]]] // Simplify;
rot2[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := kron[r2[\[Theta]], r2[\[Phi]]] // Simplify;
rot3[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := kron[r3[\[Theta]], r3[\[Phi]]] // Simplify;

(*getting the values*)
Dynamic[i]
Dynamic[b]
XY2m1 = {};
XY2m2 = {};
XY2m3 = {};
Table[{svetvals = {}; 
   Do[\[CapitalDelta] = 0; 
    Ham = (1 + g)/2 kron[\[Sigma]x, \[Sigma]x] + (1 - g)/
       2 kron[\[Sigma]y, \[Sigma]y] + \[CapitalDelta]*
       kron[\[Sigma]z, \[Sigma]z] + 
      b (KronEye[\[Sigma]z, 2, 1] + KronEye[\[Sigma]z, 2, 2]); 
    gs = Transpose[Eigsys[Ham][[2]]][[1]]; \[Rho]gs = out[gs, gs]; 
    If[i == 1, { 
      corrgs[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 
       Tr[rot1[\[Theta], \[Phi]] . \[Rho]gs];
      Svet2 = 
       1/2 (corrgs[\[Theta]1, \[Phi]1] + corrgs[\[Theta]2, \[Phi]1] + 
          corrgs[\[Theta]1, \[Phi]2] - corrgs[\[Theta]2, \[Phi]2]); 
      svet = NMaximize[
        Svet2, {\[Theta]1, \[Theta]2, \[Phi]1, \[Phi]2}]; 
      AppendTo[svetvals, ComplexExpand[Re[svet[[1]]]]]; 
      Clear[corrgs, Svet2, svet]},
     If[i == 2, { 
       corrgs[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 
        Tr[rot2[\[Theta], \[Phi]] . \[Rho]gs];
       Svet2 = 
        1/2 (corrgs[\[Theta]1, \[Phi]1] + corrgs[\[Theta]2, \[Phi]1] +
            corrgs[\[Theta]1, \[Phi]2] - corrgs[\[Theta]2, \[Phi]2]); 
       svet = NMaximize[
         Svet2, {\[Theta]1, \[Theta]2, \[Phi]1, \[Phi]2}]; 
       AppendTo[svetvals, ComplexExpand[Re[svet[[1]]]]]; 
       Clear[corrgs, Svet2, svet]},
      If[
       i == 3, { 
        corrgs[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 
         Tr[rot3[\[Theta], \[Phi]] . \[Rho]gs];
        Svet2 = 
         1/2 (corrgs[\[Theta]1, \[Phi]1] + 
            corrgs[\[Theta]2, \[Phi]1] + corrgs[\[Theta]1, \[Phi]2] - 
            corrgs[\[Theta]2, \[Phi]2]); 
        svet = NMaximize[
          Svet2, {\[Theta]1, \[Theta]2, \[Phi]1, \[Phi]2}]; 
        AppendTo[svetvals, ComplexExpand[Re[svet[[1]]]]]; 
        Clear[corrgs, Svet2, svet]}, "Failed"]]], {i, 1, 3, 1}];
   If[Max[svetvals] == Part[svetvals, 1], 
    AppendTo[XY2m1, {b, g, Max[svetvals]}], 
    If[Max[svetvals] == Part[svetvals, 2], 
     AppendTo[XY2m2, {b, g, Max[svetvals]}], 
     If[Max[svetvals] == Part[svetvals, 3], 
      AppendTo[XY2m3, {b, g, Max[svetvals]}]]]];}, {b, 0, 2, 0.2}, {g,
    0, 1, 0.05}];

(*plotting*)
M1n2 = ListPointPlot3D[XY2m1, PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"Method 1"}];
M2n2 = ListPointPlot3D[XY2m2, PlotStyle -> {Green}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"Method 2"}];
M3n2 = ListPointPlot3D[XY2m3, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"Method 3"}, AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 1]];
plane = Plot3D[z = 1, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5], Blue}];
Show[M1n2, plane, M2n2, M3n2, PlotRange -> All]
```

Here's the plot:
[image: svet against gamma and b]

And here's sort of what I want the plot to look like (but color coded)
[image: listplot3d]

I've seen a few other questions where they used colorfunction like [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13661/using-a-listdensityplot-to-map-color-onto-a-listplot3d-graph), but it seems that color function works by color coding the heights of a separate array (like a 4th dimension), whereas I've got a "4th dimension" picking the maximum of a triplet at every point.

Comment: does this give something close to what you need: `ListPlot3D[Join[XY2m1, XY2m2, XY2m3], PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
 VertexColors -> 
  Flatten[MapThread[# /. {__Real} :> #2 &][{{XY2m1, XY2m2, 
      XY2m3}, {Red, Green, Blue}}]]]`?

Comment: @kglr Yes that's amazing!

Comment: @kglr Apologies for the multiple mentions, would you mind just briefly explaining what this is part is doing, so I could make adjustments for other data? ```MapThread[# /. {__Real} :> #2 &]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may define your own color function like:

```
colfun = 
  Function[{x, y, z}, 
   Which[MemberQ[XY2m1, {x, y, z}], Red, MemberQ[XY2m2, {x, y, z}], 
    Green, _, Blue]];
legend = 
  SwatchLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"Method1", "Method2", "Method3"}, 
   LegendMarkers -> 
    Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Opacity[0.5], Rectangle[]}], 
   LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 5] &), 
   LegendMargins -> 5];

ListPlot3D[Join[XY2m1, XY2m2, XY2m3], ColorFunction -> colfun, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotStyle -> White , 
 PlotLegends -> legend]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! Might I ask how/why it's selecting some parts of the mesh to be white though?

Comment: Because only the part around the points are colored and I choose a white background.