# Plot 4D data with color as 4th dimension

Tags: plotting

I have a list of 4D data (x position, y position, amplitude, wavelength). I want to plot x, y, and amplitude on a 3D plot and have the color of the points correspond to the wavelength.
I have seen many examples using functions to define color but my wavelength cannot be expressed by an analytic function.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Could you post what you have tried and maybe a sample of your data?

Comment: Probably can find your answer here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/listplot3d-how-to-make-the-color-depending-on-a-second-list

Comment: another post might be helpful:http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19575/what-are-the-possible-ways-of-visualizing-a-4d-function-in-mathematica

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here a another possible way to visualize 4D data:

```
data = Flatten[Table[{x, y, x^2 + y^2, Sin[x - y]}, 
    {x, -Pi, Pi,Pi/10}, {y,-Pi,Pi, Pi/10}], 1];
```

You can use the function [Point](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Point.html) along with [VertexColors](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VertexColors.html).  Now the points are places using the first three elements and the color is determined by the fourth.  In this case I used Hue, but you can use whatever you prefer.

```
Graphics3D[
   Point[data[[All, 1 ;; 3]], VertexColors -> Hue /@ data[[All, 4]]],
   Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/GoldenRatio}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good solution. I only need to figure out how to normalize the Hue (my wavelength data goes from 530 to 640) Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: You should take a look at the useful function Rescale: 
Graphics3D[
   Point[data[[All, 1 ;; 3]], VertexColors -> Hue[Rescale[#,{530,640}]] /@ data[[All, 4]]],
   Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/GoldenRatio}]

Comment: IS there a way to plot the function directly, without generating the points?

Comment: This is great. Anyway to automatically add a legend that gives some idea to what values the colors correspond?

Comment: @Kvothe I'm not sure if you'd count this as automatic or not, but `Legended[Graphics3D[
  Point[data[[All, 1 ;; 3]], VertexColors -> Hue /@ data[[All, 4]]], 
  Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/GoldenRatio}], 
 BarLegend[{Hue, MinMax@data[[All, 4]]}]]`

Comment: @chuy, yes, great thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can try the following approach. Let's first generate some 4D data:

```
ndata = 100;
data = Transpose[{RandomReal[{-1, 1}, ndata], 
    RandomReal[{-1, 1}, ndata], RandomReal[{0, 10}, ndata], 
    RandomReal[{400, 800}, ndata]}];
```

Now we use the first three columns as $x$, $y$ and $z$ coordinates, whereas the 4th column specifies the color of each point. The color range is specified via the `Blend` function that specifies that a value of 400 should correspond to `Darker[Green]`, a value of 600 to `Yellow` and a value of 800 to `Red`. All other values are blended colors.

```
ListPointPlot3D[List /@ data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]], 
 PlotStyle -> ({PointSize[Large], 
      Blend[{{400, Darker[Green]}, {600, Yellow}, {800, 
         Red}}, #1]} & /@ Flatten[data[[All, {4}]]])]
```

[image]

Comment: This also works. Thanks for the help.  Too bad I can't select 2 answers as solution.