# Colorbar doesn't appear

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

I have a list of data with dimensions $(2000,4)$.

I plotted it using `ListPointPlot3D`, setting the fourth dimension as the color. As follows:

```
ListPointPlot3D[List /@ data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]], 
  PlotStyle -> ({PointSize[Large], 
       Blend[{{0, Darker[Green]}, {5, Yellow}, {10, Red}}, #1]} & /@ 
     Flatten[data[[All, {4}]]]), RotationAction -> "Clip"]
```

I want to show the colorbar, I tried the function `ShowLegend`, but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have version 9, which has new legending functions, this is how I would do it.

```
data = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, Sin[ x y/50], Cos[x y/50]}, {x, 0, 
     10 π, π/10}, {y, 0, 10 π, π/10}], 1];

ListPointPlot3D[data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]], 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["IslandColors"][z]], 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{ColorData["IslandColors"], {-1, 1}}]]
```

[image]

`ShowLegend` is a function from the old and much deviled `PlotLegends` package. If you intended to use *that*, you may have forgotten to include the package using `Needs`.

In earlier versions you would write something like:

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]

ShowLegend[
 ListPointPlot3D[data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]], 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, 
    ColorData["IslandColors"][z]]], {ColorData["IslandColors"][
    1 - #1] &, 10, " 1", "-1", LegendPosition -> {1.1, -.4}}]
```

[image]

Much of what you wrote yourself doesn't seem to make sense. The `List/@` part is unnesessary as you can see from how I handle the data matrix. `PlotStyle` doesn't take a pure function as argument. Where did you encounter a construction like that?

Comment: I found it here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20023/plot-4d-data-with-color-as-4th-dimension, in the second answer.