# Modified ListPlot, how to speed it up

Tags: plotting, graphics, performance-tuning

I use Mathematica almost every day for several jobs (computations, graphics, etc.). I admit that this software contains much more options (capabilities) than one user may need. Well, not always since I hit a snag. Let me be more specific:

I have a data set which contains hundreds of thousands of sub-lists composing of four items; the first two are the $(x,y)$ coordinates the third is a real number $t$ and the four is always an integer $i$. For the purpose of this question let's generate a random data

```
n = 50000;
data = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[{10^-2, 10^4}], 
RandomInteger[{0, 2}]}, {i, 1, n}];
```

OK, now we want to create a two-dimensional plot depicting all the $(x,y)$ points with $i \ne 0$ and assign to each point a color according to the value $log_{10}f$. One may reasonably argue, that for what I describe here I need either `ListDensityPlot` or `ListContourPlot`. Unfortunately, both modules come by default with a nasty drawback which is fatal in my case. The problem is that both modules spread the colors or in other words, they try to join the colors between the points. There should be an option like `Joined -> False` but it isn't. Perhaps this should be forwarded to Wolfram, so as to be considered for the new version of the program.

So, for creating my plot I have to push the program to the limits.

First, we filter the data, we select only those sub lists with $i ne 0$ and we define a color function (for those which $n = 0$ we assign gray color).

```
valrange = {-2, 4};
data[[All, 3]] = Rescale[Log10[data[[All, 3]]] // N, valrange];
colfunc[x_, cf_] := If[x[[4]] == 0, Gray, ColorData[cf][1 - x[[3]]]];
```

Then, more labor work is needed to create the corresponding pallet explaining the colors

```
Clear[colorbar]
colorbar[{min_, max_}, colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 150] := 
DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, min, max}, AspectRatio -> 10, 
PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotPoints -> {2, divs}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {{None, Row[{Subscript["log", "10"], "(", Subscript["t", "esc"], ")"}]}, {None, None}}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 17], 
FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 15, Plain], 
ColorFunction -> colorFunction]
```

and finally use `ListPlot` to do the job

```
With[{opts = {ImageSize -> {Automatic, 550}}, cf = "Rainbow"}, 
 Row[{Show[
ListPlot[List /@ data[[All, {1, 2}]], 
 PlotStyle -> ({PointSize[0.005], colfunc[#, cf]} & /@ 1. data), 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, RotateLabel -> False, 
 Axes -> None, FrameTicks -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], 
 ImagePadding -> {{60, 20}, {60, 20}}, opts, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style["Test 2", FontSize -> 20, Black, 
   FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]], PlotRange -> 0.9, 
PlotRangeClipping -> True], 
Show[colorbar[valrange, ColorData[cf][1 - #] &], 
ImagePadding -> {{20, 60}, {60, 40}}, opts]}]]
```

This piece of code works nice when the number of points is relatively small, let's say $n < 10^4$. My real data however, correspond to $n > 5 \times 10^4$. My CPU (Dual Core at 2.2GHz) needs about 15 minutes for this task. On the other hand, when I enter the same amount of data in already built-in modules (i.e use `ListPlot` to plot only the coordinates) the required time does not exceed 60 secs.

So, the question: how can I speed up this procedure and lower the CPU time down to let's say no more than 2 minutes?  (For testing keep $n = 50000$ which corresponds roughly to a real data set).

Comment: I think your problem can be described using less than 25% of words from above :). Is [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20023/5478) helpful?

Comment: @Kuba The post you indicated contains 3D data with the fourth dimension is the color, it has no colorbar and most of all, if the data were much more, like in my case, it will probably very time consuming!

Comment: `Point[....,  VertexColors -> ...]` tends to be quite efficient even for large number of points:  `Graphics3D[
   Point[#[[All, ;; 3]], VertexColors -> Hue /@ #[[All, 4]]]] &@
 RandomReal[1, {10^5, 4}]`

Comment: Have you tried with `InterpolationOrder-> 0` while using the `ListDensityPlot` or `ListContourPlot`?

Comment: @ssch The palette should be `Rainbow`. But you don't explain how this can be incorporated in my code.

Comment: @PlatoManiac I tried all options of these two modules but with no result.

Comment: It was in response to "it will probably very time consuming!" It wont be.

Comment: @ssch OK, show us the magic then! Note, take that all aspect should be operational i.e. the colorbar the special gray color.

Comment: Note that this site is for getting help, not for others to do the coding for you

Comment: @ssch I agree! I am not asking you to make the code from scratch. I 'm asking how to speed up the existing one. However, if you think that the existing one cannot be upgraded and therefore a new one is needed, at least try to include the capabilities of the original one.

Comment: re @kuba's comment on brevity, remember Pascal's "I have made this longer than usual because I have not had time to make it shorter." You can focus on the main problem, and worry about the coloring and formatting later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quick test of @ssch's suggestion in the comments:

```
n = 100000;
data = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[{10^-2, 10^4}], 
    RandomInteger[{0, 2}]}, {i, 1, n}];
colfunc[x_, cf_] := If[x[[4]] == 0, Gray, ColorData[cf][1 - x[[3]]]];

Graphics[{PointSize[Tiny], 
  Point[#[[1 ;; 2]], VertexColors -> colfunc[#, "Rainbow"]] & /@ data}]
```

takes about 10 seconds on my 2011 iMac. For no good reason:

[image]

(I think I've discovered dark matter...)

Comment: `Blend["Rainbow", ...]` is much faster. Also `Point[pts, VertexColors->colorlist]` is much faster than list of points.

Comment: Yes, it's working like a charm! Less than 10 sec! Please make an update with the colorbar and labels so as to see if everything is OK.

Comment: By the way, dark matter is by definition dark (non-visible) so, why do you think you discover it?!

Comment: No need to update your post; I checked that everything else is OK! Now the plot needs about 3.5 secs!!! Simply amazing. Many many thanks again.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z It was ssch's idea, really, so you could vote up [one of these](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1517/ssch?tab=answers) by way of thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I would pre-process the data:

```
n = 50000;
data = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[{10^-2, 10^4}], RandomInteger[2]}, 
             {i, 1, n}];

data[[ ;; , 3]] = Map[Blend["Rainbow", 1 - #] &,
                      Rescale[Log10[data[[ ;; , 3]]], {-2, 4}, {0, 1}]
                     ];

data[[ ;; , 3]] = ReplacePart[data[[ ;; , 3]], Position[data[[ ;; , 4]], 0] -> Gray];

bar = ArrayPlot[Array[# &, {121, 1}], Frame -> {{None, True}, {None, None}}, 
         FrameTicks -> {{None, Transpose[{#, Reverse@Rescale[#, {1, 121}, {-2, 4}]
                        } &@Range[1, 121, 20]]}, {None, None}}, 
         AspectRatio -> 10, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> {Automatic, 400}];


Row[{ Graphics[Point[data[[ ;; , ;; 2]], VertexColors -> data[[ ;; , 3]]],
               BaseStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[5], ImageSize -> 400],
     bar}]
```

[image]

Comment: gray color corresponds to i=0 but f->ininity not 0. So, gray should not be in the colorbar at all.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z ah, of course I don't know what I was thinking about :)