# ListPointPlot3D with coloured 4th Dimension from List

Tags: plotting

Similar to http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/May/msg00133.html or [Plot 4D data with color as 4th dimension](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20023/plot-4d-data-with-color-as-4th-dimension), I would like to plot single points `{x, y, z}` in 3D with a 4th value `Q` as color function where each dataset has its own `Q` value. So i cannot use a function because each `Q` has to be connected to its `{x, y, z}`-set, but the `z` level is constant for each dataset. For example:

```
DataA: {{xA1, yA2, zA, QA1}, {xA2, yA2, zA, QA2}, ...
DataB: {{xB1, yB2, zB, QB1}, {xB2, yB2, zB, QB2}, ...
```

How would this be implemented here?:

```
circle3D[centre_: {0, 0, 0}, radius_: 20, normal_: {0, 0, 1}, angle_: {0, 2 Pi}] :=Composition[Line, Map[RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, normal}, 
centre], #] &, Map[Append[#, Last@centre] &, #] &, 
Append[DeleteDuplicates[Most@#], Last@#] &, Level[#, {-2}] &,
MeshPrimitives[#, 1] &, DiscretizeRegion, If]
[First@Differences@angle >= 2 Pi, Circle[Most@centre, radius],
Circle[Most@centre, radius, angle]]

colors = 
  {{1, RGBColor[1, 0.11, 0.02, 0.75]}, 
   {2, RGBColor[1, 0.22, 0.23, 0.75]}, 
   {3, RGBColor[1, 0.52, 0, 0.75]}, 
   {4, RGBColor[0.93, 0.79, 0.05, 0.75]}, 
   {5, RGBColor[0.63, 0.84, 0.09, 0.75]}, 
   {6, RGBColor[0.4, 0.86, 0.15, 0.75]}, 
   {7, RGBColor[0.1, 0.86, 0.17, 0.75]}};

Data1 = 
  {{20, 0, z1, 3}, {10, 0, z1, 3}, {0, 0, z1, 3.67}, {-10, 0, z1, 3}, 
   {-20, 0, z1, 3}, {0, 10, z1, 3}, {0, 20, z1, 3}, {0, 10, z1, 3}, 
   {0, -20, z1, 3}, {z1, 100}};
Data2 = 
  {{20, 0, z2, 2.67}, {10, 0, z2, 3.33}, {0, 0, z2, 4}, {0, 10, z2, 3.67}, 
   {0, 20, z2, 2.33}, {0, -10, z2, 3.67}, {0, -20, z2, 2.33}, {-20, 0, z2, 2.67}, 
   {-10, 0, z2, 3.33}, {z2, 200}};

c1 = Graphics3D[{Dashed, circle3D[{0, 0, 100}, 20]}];
c2 = Graphics3D[{Dashed, circle3D[{0, 0, 200}, 20]}];

Show[
  ListPointPlot3D[{Data1, Data2},
    Axes -> True, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
    ColorFunction -> (Blend[colors, #1] &),
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    Boxed -> False,
    PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02],
    PlotRange -> Automatic,
    ImageSize -> Large,
    ViewPoint -> {0.8 Pi, -1.5 Pi, 0.20 Pi}],
  c1, c2]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot 4D data with color as 4th dimension](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20023/plot-4d-data-with-color-as-4th-dimension)

Comment: Can you point out what does not work for you in the solutions proposed in the question "Plot 4D data with color as 4th dimension" that  you link to? Also, why is the last entry in your `Data` lists completely different from the others? Can you give us the actual list of data you want to plot? Can you define `circle3D`, or link to its definition?

Comment: You can not plot `Data1` and `Data2` as you currently define them with `ListPointPlot3D` because they are not lists of 3D points. You must transform them into such lists and while doing so assign numeric values to `z1` and `z2`.

Comment: @StephanJ, in what way is [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20029/9490) not the perfect solution to your problem?  As your problem is stated, that's the answer, so if it doesn't work for you, let us know why.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Sorry, i missed the circle3D definition, I added this one. My problem with the linked examples are, that there are always functions added, as with the flatten or table option. I here have points in x,y and z position with a certain value for the color (4th value), this value is unique for each data point and i want to link this 4th value to the color function. Only the z value is the same for each data list because all points of one list are located in one z level (Data2 --> z2, and so on). I currently do not now how to transform the data as m_goldberg suggested.

Comment: You still haven't fixed the fundamental problem that `Data1` and `Data2` are not suitable arguments for `ListPointPlot3D` because they not lists of 3D points. Until you do that, I see no reason to reopen this question.

Comment: Ok, im afraid but exactly here is my problem. To bring these datasets of 4D points in a form to further use the transpose option like in the linked example is my bottleneck here. There a function is used. Up to now i could not combine my datasets with this method. The graph itself is already finished.

Comment: Update: Question might be deleted. I found my (unfortunatly) very basic mistake. The linked answer fits very well. Thanks though.