# Color points in ListPointPlot3D

Tags: plotting, color

I have some 3d points with coordinates and a value assigned to each point. I want to plot the points and depending on the value use a different color.

I have tried to use the answer in [ListPlot3D - How to make the Color depending on a second list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/listplot3d-how-to-make-the-color-depending-on-a-second-list?rq=1), but Interpolation does not work.

```
Interpolation::udeg: Interpolation on unstructured grids is currently only supported for InterpolationOrder->1 ...
Interpolation::femimq: "The element mesh has insufficient quality ...
Interpolation::fememtlq: "The quality -1.8665289611526646`*^-14 of the underlying mesh is too low..."
```

Here is a sample of points like the ones i want to plot (with the same structure {{{x,y,z},value},...} I used while trying to interpolate):

```
data =  {{{710, 76.2867, 39.966}, -1.70615}, {{710, 40.2502, 
   73.2953}, -5.06218}, {{710, -9.21471, 
   82.1714}, -6.7294}, {{710, -55.6054, 
   63.633}, -6.15158}, {{710, -83.4447, 
   23.865}, -3.5215}, {{710, -83.4447, -23.865}, 
  0.283382}, {{710, -55.6054, -63.633}, 
  3.99366}, {{710, -9.21471, -82.1714}, 
  6.37148}, {{710, 40.2502, -73.2953}, 
  6.62355}, {{710, 76.2867, -39.966}, 
  4.66578}, {{720, 68.9417, 52.0067}, -1.63914}, {{720, 30.1636, 
   78.3901}, -4.60195}, {{720, -17.4658, 
   81.7705}, -6.19948}, {{720, -59.9699, 
   61.1558}, -5.96296}, {{720, -84.8763, 
   22.5954}, -3.96179}, {{720, -84.8763, -22.5954}, -0.783197}, \
{{720, -59.9699, -61.1558}, 2.64008}, {{720, -17.4658, -81.7705}, 
  5.3035}, {{720, 30.1636, -78.3901}, 
  6.4255}, {{720, 68.9417, -52.0067}, 
  5.67684}, {{730, 63.9679, 58.7083}, -1.52177}, {{730, 24.0419, 
   81.1198}, -4.46802}, {{730, -22.4026, 
   81.5373}, -6.17621}, {{730, -62.7731, 
   59.8475}, -6.1832}, {{730, -86.1239, 
   21.9312}, -4.48709}, {{730, -86.1239, -21.9312}, -1.54775}, {{730, \
-62.7731, -59.8475}, 1.83788}, {{730, -22.4026, -81.5373}, 
  4.75184}, {{730, 24.0419, -81.1198}, 
  6.40409}, {{730, 63.9679, -58.7083}, 
  6.34663}, {{740, 61.2769, 62.4556}, -1.49987}, {{740, 20.7044, 
   82.8065}, -4.47847}, {{740, -25.2379, 
   81.6812}, -6.26191}, {{740, -64.6346, 
   59.3714}, -6.38765}, {{740, -87.2679, 
   21.6633}, -4.82307}, {{740, -87.2679, -21.6633}, -1.97396}, {{740, \
-64.6346, -59.3714}, 1.42075}, {{740, -25.2379, -81.6812}, 
  4.48062}, {{740, 20.7044, -82.8065}, 
  6.41207}, {{740, 61.2769, -62.4556}, 
  6.71416}, {{750, 59.7262, 65.}, -1.54366}, {{750, 18.6359, 
   84.1306}, -4.53748}, {{750, -27.1527, 
   82.0514}, -6.34961}, {{750, -66.0958, 
   59.2865}, -6.52319}, {{750, -88.3759, 
   21.5753}, -5.01446}, {{750, -88.3759, -21.5753}, -2.20378}, {{750, \
-66.0958, -59.2865}, 1.20027}, {{750, -27.1527, -82.0514}, 
  4.33949}, {{750, 18.6359, -84.1306}, 
  6.42248}, {{750, 59.7262, -65.}, 
  6.92411}, {{760, 61.2449, 65.}, -1.72584}, {{760, 19.681, 
   84.8354}, -4.65037}, {{760, -26.8947, 
   83.0673}, -6.35623}, {{760, -66.6216, 
   60.1459}, -6.40902}, {{760, -89.3832, 
   21.9083}, -4.7953}, {{760, -89.3832, -21.9083}, -1.92601}, {{760, \
-66.6216, -60.1459}, 1.46819}, {{760, -26.8947, -83.0673}, 
  4.52296}, {{760, 19.681, -84.8354}, 6.46039}, {{760, 61.2449, -65.},
   6.78711}, {{770, 62.7788, 65.}, -1.89666}, {{770, 20.7417, 
   85.5551}, -4.76174}, {{770, -26.63, 
   84.1059}, -6.37081}, {{770, -67.1526, 
   61.0252}, -6.31001}, {{770, -90.404, 
   22.2492}, -4.59499}, {{770, -90.404, -22.2492}, -1.66684}, {{770, \
-67.1526, -61.0252}, 1.72133}, {{770, -26.63, -84.1059}, 
  4.69812}, {{770, 20.7417, -85.5551}, 6.4979}, {{770, 62.7788, -65.},
   6.65779}, {{780, 64.3267, 65.}, -2.05642}, {{780, 21.8171, 
   86.2893}, -4.87143}, {{780, -26.3591, 
   85.1668}, -6.39277}, {{780, -67.6891, 
   61.924}, -6.22532}, {{780, -91.4383, 
   22.5978}, -4.41255}, {{780, -91.4383, -22.5978}, -1.4253}, {{780, \
-67.6891, -61.924}, 1.96056}, {{780, -26.3591, -85.1668}, 
  4.86561}, {{780, 21.8171, -86.2893}, 
  6.53535}, {{780, 64.3267, -65.}, 
  6.53608}, {{790, 65.8877, 65.}, -2.20549}, {{790, 22.9061, 
   87.0374}, -4.9793}, {{790, -26.0827, 
   86.2491}, -6.42158}, {{790, -68.2312, 
   62.8416}, -6.15407}, {{790, -92.4859, 
   22.9538}, -4.24693}, {{790, -92.4859, -22.9538}, -1.20032}, {{790, \
-68.2312, -62.8416}, 2.18678}, {{790, -26.0827, -86.2491}, 
  5.0261}, {{790, 22.9061, -87.0374}, 6.57302}, {{790, 65.8877, -65.},
   6.42184}, {{800, 67.4603, 65.}, -2.34437}, {{800, 24.0077, 
   87.7988}, -5.08531}, {{800, -25.8012, 
   87.3517}, -6.45667}, {{800, -68.779, 
   63.7772}, -6.09537}, {{800, -93.5467, 
   23.3169}, -4.09705}, {{800, -93.5467, -23.3169}, -0.990801}, \
{{800, -68.779, -63.7772}, 2.40096}, {{800, -25.8012, -87.3517}, 
  5.18022}, {{800, 24.0077, -87.7988}, 
  6.61113}, {{800, 67.4603, -65.}, 
  6.31485}, {{810, 69.0434, 65.}, -2.47359}, {{810, 25.1207, 
   88.5725}, -5.18945}, {{810, -25.5155, 
   88.4737}, -6.49756}, {{810, -69.3327, 
   64.7299}, -6.04832}, {{810, -94.6203, 
   23.6868}, -3.96181}, {{810, -94.6203, -23.6868}, -0.795645}, \
{{810, -69.3327, -64.7299}, 2.604}, {{810, -25.5155, -88.4737}, 
  5.32856}, {{810, 25.1207, -88.5725}, 
  6.64988}, {{810, 69.0434, -65.}, 
  6.21484}, {{820, 70.6354, 65.}, -2.59374}, {{820, 26.2439, 
   89.3578}, -5.29172}, {{820, -25.2263, 
   89.6136}, -6.54373}, {{820, -69.8923, 
   65.6985}, -6.01208}, {{820, -95.7067, 
   24.063}, -3.84015}, {{820, -95.7067, -24.063}, -0.613773}, {{820, \
-69.8923, -65.6985}, 2.79682}, {{820, -25.2263, -89.6136}, 
  5.47171}, {{820, 26.2439, -89.3578}, 
  6.68942}, {{820, 70.6354, -65.}, 
  6.1215}, {{830, 72.2352, 65.}, -2.70539}, {{830, 27.376, 
   90.1535}, -5.39219}, {{830, -24.9342, 
   90.7701}, -6.59475}, {{830, -70.4581, 
   66.6819}, -5.98578}, {{830, -96.8055, 
   24.445}, -3.73102}, {{830, -96.8055, -24.445}, -0.444143}, {{830, \
-70.4581, -66.6819}, 2.98027}, {{830, -24.9342, -90.7701}, 
  5.61019}, {{830, 27.376, -90.1535}, 6.72985}, {{830, 72.2352, -65.},
   6.03451}, {{840, 73.8415, 65.}, -2.80912}, {{840, 28.5157, 
   90.9587}, -5.49089}, {{840, -24.6401, 
   91.9416}, -6.65017}, {{840, -71.0301, 
   67.6788}, -5.96864}, {{840, -97.9163, 
   24.8325}, -3.63343}, {{840, -97.9163, -24.8325}, -0.285765}, \
{{840, -71.0301, -67.6788}, 3.15515}, {{840, -24.6401, -91.9416}, 
  5.74449}, {{840, 28.5157, -90.9587}, 
  6.77127}, {{840, 73.8415, -65.}, 
  5.95354}, {{850, 75.4529, 65.}, -2.90552}, {{850, 29.6618, 
   91.7722}, -5.58791}, {{850, -24.3446, 
   93.1265}, -6.70959}, {{850, -71.6084, 
   68.6877}, -5.95989}, {{850, -99.039, 
   25.2247}, -3.54644}, {{850, -99.039, -25.2247}, -0.137702}, {{850, \
-71.6084, -68.6877}, 3.32222}, {{850, -24.3446, -93.1265}, 
  5.87505}, {{850, 29.6618, -91.7722}, 
  6.81372}, {{850, 75.4529, -65.}, 
  5.87826}, {{860, 77.3407, 64.7177}, -2.99704}, {{860, 31.1154, 
   92.5048}, -5.69395}, {{860, -23.8286, 
   94.3717}, -6.7843}, {{860, -72.0957, 
   69.7953}, -5.96259}, {{860, -100.161, 
   25.662}, -3.45904}, {{860, -100.161, -25.662}, 
  0.0248265}, {{860, -72.0957, -69.7953}, 
  3.51282}, {{860, -23.8286, -94.3717}, 
  6.0276}, {{860, 31.1154, -92.5048}, 
  6.8645}, {{860, 77.3407, -64.7177}, 
  5.78903}, {{870, 78.7876, 64.8939}, -3.07893}, {{870, 32.0813, 
   93.3861}, -5.78126}, {{870, -23.6704, 
   95.5476}, -6.84371}, {{870, -72.7481, 
   70.769}, -5.96672}, {{870, -101.314, 
   26.0367}, -3.39756}, {{870, -101.314, -26.0367}, 
  0.139378}, {{870, -72.7481, -70.769}, 
  3.64684}, {{870, -23.6704, -95.5476}, 
  6.13589}, {{870, 32.0813, -93.3861}, 
  6.90471}, {{870, 78.7876, -64.8939}, 
  5.73653}, {{880, 80.6211, 64.6615}, -3.15671}, {{880, 33.4818, 
   94.1425}, -5.88291}, {{880, -23.1974, 
   96.7996}, -6.92471}, {{880, -73.267, 
   71.876}, -5.98527}, {{880, -102.461, 
   26.473}, -3.33227}, {{880, -102.461, -26.473}, 
  0.27838}, {{880, -73.267, -71.876}, 
  3.81791}, {{880, -23.1974, -96.7996}, 
  6.27782}, {{880, 33.4818, -94.1425}, 
  6.9572}, {{880, 80.6211, -64.6615}, 
  5.66249}, {{890, 82.8576, 63.9689}, -3.2279}, {{890, 35.3509, 
   94.7482}, -6.00244}, {{890, -22.3795, 
   98.1257}, -7.03478}, {{890, -73.6376, 
   73.1246}, -6.02636}, {{890, -103.599, 
   26.9754}, -3.26881}, {{890, -103.599, -26.9754}, 
  0.440363}, {{890, -73.6376, -73.1246}, 
  4.02844}, {{890, -22.3795, -98.1257}, 
  6.45772}, {{890, 35.3509, -94.7482}, 
  7.02564}, {{890, 82.8576, -63.9689}, 
  5.56797}, {{900, 85.5153, 62.742}, -3.28935}, {{900, 37.7348, 
   95.1657}, -6.14521}, {{900, -21.1749, 
   99.5221}, -7.18461}, {{900, -73.8394, 
   74.5265}, -6.10099}, {{900, -104.726, 
   27.5507}, -3.21396}, {{900, -104.726, -27.5507}, 
  0.62502}, {{900, -73.8394, -74.5265}, 
  4.28371}, {{900, -21.1749, -99.5221}, 
  6.68306}, {{900, 37.7348, -95.1657}, 
  7.11542}, {{900, 85.5153, -62.742}, 
  5.45328}, {{910, 88.6145, 60.8757}, -3.33687}, {{910, 40.6962, 
   95.34}, -6.31928}, {{910, -19.5247, 
   100.983}, -7.38973}, {{910, -73.8433, 
   76.0979}, -6.22462}, {{910, -105.839, 
   28.2085}, -3.17617}, {{910, -105.839, -28.2085}, 
  0.834057}, {{910, -73.8433, -76.0979}, 
  4.59376}, {{910, -19.5247, -100.983}, 
  6.96637}, {{910, 40.6962, -95.34}, 
  7.23464}, {{910, 88.6145, -60.8757}, 
  5.31746}, {{920, 92.1776, 58.2182}, -3.36434}, {{920, 44.3228, 
   95.1902}, -6.53729}, {{920, -17.3447, 
   102.497}, -7.67401}, {{920, -73.6069, 
   77.8626}, -6.42023}, {{920, -106.93, 
   28.9628}, -3.16669}, {{920, -106.93, -28.9628}, 
  1.07268}, {{920, -73.6069, -77.8626}, 
  4.97675}, {{920, -17.3447, -102.497}, 
  7.32885}, {{920, 44.3228, -95.1902}, 
  7.39599}, {{920, 92.1776, -58.2182}, 
  5.15723}, {{930, 96.2294, 54.54}, -3.36165}, {{930, 48.7434, 
   94.5914}, -6.82032}, {{930, -14.5072, 
   104.05}, -8.07699}, {{930, -73.0659, 
   79.8561}, -6.72522}, {{930, -107.993, 
   29.8352}, -3.20221}, {{930, -107.993, -29.8352}, 
  1.35262}, {{930, -73.0659, -79.8561}, 
  5.46614}, {{930, -14.5072, -104.05}, 
  7.80794}, {{930, 48.7434, -94.5914}, 
  7.62062}, {{930, 96.2294, -54.54}, 
  4.96478}, {{940, 100.797, 49.4669}, -3.30952}, {{940, 54.1638, 
   93.3353}, -7.207}, {{940, -10.8032, 
   105.61}, -8.67185}, {{940, -72.1134, 
   82.1372}, -7.20822}, {{940, -109.014, 
   30.8612}, -3.31155}, {{940, -109.014, -30.8612}, 
  1.69917}, {{940, -72.1134, -82.1372}, 
  6.12786}, {{940, -10.8032, -105.61}, 
  8.47543}, {{940, 54.1638, -93.3353}, 
  7.94724}, {{940, 100.797, -49.4669}, 
  4.7221}, {{950, 105.91, 42.2999}, -3.16263}, {{950, 60.9619, 
   91.0248}, -7.77972}, {{950, -5.83869, 
   107.12}, -9.61826}, {{950, -70.5463, 
   84.8165}, -8.01919}, {{950, -109.965, 
   32.1088}, -3.55572}, {{950, -109.965, -32.1088}, 
  2.17212}, {{950, -70.5463, -84.8165}, 
  7.11111}, {{950, -5.83869, -107.12}, 
  9.49076}, {{950, 60.9619, -91.0248}, 
  8.45805}, {{950, 105.91, -42.2999}, 
  4.38318}, {{960, 111.6, 31.328}, -2.77116}, {{960, 70.0549, 
   86.668}, -8.77145}, {{960, 1.36414, 
   108.425}, -11.3871}, {{960, -67.8552, 
   88.1692}, -9.60467}, {{960, -110.782, 
   33.7488}, -4.11473}, {{960, -110.782, -33.7488}, 
  2.9554}, {{960, -67.8552, -88.1692}, 
  8.86615}, {{960, 1.36414, -108.425}, 
  11.3272}, {{960, 70.0549, -86.668}, 
  9.38486}, {{960, 111.6, -31.328}, 3.79183}};
```

How would you do it? It's probable something simple but i haven't found how to make it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 2:** And ... don't forget `BubbleChart3D`:

Modify `{x,y,z}` triples to `{x, y, z, 1}` and `Style` each each based on the second column values in `data`:

```
data2 = Style[Join[#, {1}], ColorData[{"Rainbow", {min, max}}][#2]] & @@@ data;
```

and use with `BubbleChart3D`:

```
BubbleChart3D[data2, BubbleSizes -> {.01, .01}, ViewPoint -> {1.5, -1.5, 2.5}, 
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

---

**Original post:**

```
{min, max} = Through@{Min, Max}@data[[All, 2]];
```

Simplest way is to use `Graphics3D`

```
Graphics3D[{ColorData[{"Rainbow", {min, max}}][#2], PointSize[Large], 
    Point@#} & @@@ data, ViewPoint -> {1.5, -1.5, 2.5}]
```

[image]

You get the same picture using `ListPointPlot3D` with a custom color function:

```
ClearAll[intf, cf]
intf = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
cf = Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData[{"Rainbow", {min, max}}][intf[x, y, z]]];

ListPointPlot3D[data[[All, 1]], BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large],
 ColorFunction -> cf,
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, BoxRatios -> 1, 
 ViewPoint -> {1.5, -1.5, 2.5}]
```

**Update:** A simpler way to define the color function without using interpolation:

```
cf = Function[{x, y, z}, 
   ColorData[{"Rainbow", {min, max}}][{x, y, z} /. Rule @@@ data]];
```

Comment: @mnunos,  my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: I think mnunos should vote up once the asnwer is accepted!!!!

Comment: @ramesh, thank you for the vote. Sometimes new users are not aware that they can _both_  accept and upvote.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you mean something like this:

```
list = Flatten[Table[{i - 15, j - 15, 
     5 Exp[-(((i - 15)^2 + (j - 15)^2)/16)]}, {i, 0, 30}, {j, 0, 30}], 1];

ListPlot3D[list,
 PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 3, MaxPlotPoints -> 25,
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["Rainbow"][z]]]
```

[image]

I choose the `"Rainbow"` colorset but you of course can change it..

Comment: Not exactly, calculating the value is not so easy and i couldn't express it as a simple function like in your example (I have already seen almost the same in another question). kgulers answer is what i was searching. Thanks anyway.