# Coloring points via "TemperatureMap"

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, color

I have a collection of 3D points, and each is associated with a real number in [0,1]. A typical element looks like `{{x,y,z},c}` where `c` is the number to determine the color. (Sample code to generate random data below.) I would like to plot those points, coloring each according to `ColorData["TemperatureMap"]`. I have been unable to figure out how to get this to work, to arrange for `ColorFunction->(???)` to use that parameter `c` rather than `x`, `y`, or `z` to index into `"TemperatureMap"`. This is likely straightforward for those
(unlike me) who have mastered
`ColorFunction` and `ColorData`.

```
SeedRandom[1]; n = 10; 
pts = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3}], {n}]; 
ptsc = Map[{#, RandomReal[]} &, pts];
```

Comment: A frequently asked question (and duplicate).  2D version: [(1300)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1300/121), [(5185)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5185/121).  3D duplicates: [(20023)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20023/121),
[(77859)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77859/121),
[(78289)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78289/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thanks for all those links!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mr.Wizard pointed out, multiple interesting solutions to your problem have been proposed on this site. I just wanted to add an observation here.

I realize that you did not say so explicitly, but I would think that many users would try some combination of `ListPointPlot3D` for this kind of task. However, it has been my impression when using the *3D list plotting functions that they may not always be as polished and agile as their 2D counterpart. I have had a few problems with them, and I am now a bit wary.

I find it often easier to reproduce their behavior by constructing a `Graphics3D` object explicitly; it is my understanding that it's what those functions do anyway. Similarly in this case, the following is the method I would have come up with, when confronted with your problem. I am using your mock data definitions, just with a few more points.

```
Graphics3D[
 {PointSize[0.03], ColorData["TemperatureMap"][ #[[2]] ], Point[ #[[1]] ]} & /@ ptsc,
 Axes -> True, Background -> Black
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(I added a black background because the point colors otherwise had very poor contrast on white; of course it's not required.)

---

**Update:**

Exactly the same goal can be achieved more cleanly following Guess who it is's suggestion of using `Apply` to improve on the somewhat ugly `Part` expressions I had above:

```
Graphics3D[
 {PointSize[0.03],
  {ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#2], Point[#1]} & @@@ ptsc
  }, Axes -> True, Background -> Black]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I needed, the syntax for `ColorData["TemperatureMap"][ #[[2]] ]`.

Comment: Also possible: `{PointSize[0.03], {ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#2], Point[#1]} & @@@ ptsc}`. The `PointSize[]` will be applied globally anyway, and you can use `Apply[]` to avoid clumsiness with `Part[]`.

Comment: @J.M. Good point about the global `PointSize`. As for the `Apply[]`, I'll be honest: those `@@@` still hurt my brain sometimes, but it is undoubtedly more elegant here. I really need to use it more!

Comment: @J.M. I added your version with `Apply` as an alternative to my answer. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Of course I don't mind; that's why I put it in. :)

Comment: @J. M.: May I ask: What does `@@@` accomplish? Can you unpack for me the three @-signs?

Comment: Hello, @Joseph! `f @@@ list` is shorthand for `Apply[f, list, {1}]`; it changes the heads of the elements of `list` at the first level (`{1}`) to `f`. So, if you do something like `f @@@ {{u, v}, {x, y}}`, you get `{f[u, v], f[x, y]}` as the result, with for instance the `List` head of `{u, v}` getting turned into `f`.

Comment: I am a longstanding proponent of manual plotting with `Graphics` and `Graphics3D` in many cases, so +1.  Note that if you can make use of `VertexColors` it will be considerably more efficient.  (See the marked duplicate for example, or other links below the question.)