# 4D Plot: ListPlot3D + Colorfunction

Tags: plotting

just in case someone has a similar problem: 
I wanted to visualize a 4D Listdata. 
The first 3 coordinates describe a surface and the fourth dimension a scalar value.

A classical example are Finite Element results for shells, where stress is plotted on a surface; or alternatively a temperature-field on a 3D surface.

I found some very helpful solutions [[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32844/need-4d-plot-3d-color-for-function/32859#32859),[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13661/using-a-listdensityplot-to-map-color-onto-a-listplot3d-graph),[3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/listplot3d-how-to-make-the-color-depending-on-a-second-list/6523#6523),[4](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50501/smooth-4d-3d-color-plot-from-discrete-points)], but none of them really solved my problem, because I wanted to have a continuous function and not a point cloud, and it couldn't get the last solution working in my case.
I thought the solution might be worth sharing:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me finally this thing here worked:
Function f describes the surface; function g the colorfunction.

Creating datapoints for standalone example:

```
List4D = {};
f[{x_, y_}] := 1/2*(x^2 + y^2)
g[{x_, y_}] := x + y
xyList = Tuples[Range[-1, 1, 1/30], 2];
For[i = 1, i <= Length[xyList], i = i + 1, 
 List4D = Append[List4D, 
Flatten[{xyList[[i]], f[xyList[[i]]], g[xyList[[i]]]}]];]
```

Plot surace + color

```
nf = Nearest[List4D[[All, {1, 2}]] -> Rescale[List4D[[All, 4]]]];
colfun = ColorData["Rainbow"]@First@nf[{#1, #2}] &;
ListPlot3D[List4D[[All, {1, 2, 3}]], ColorFunction -> colfun, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Just in case you need a BarLegend:

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {Min[List4D[[All, 4]]], Max[List4D[[All, 4]]]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: worked like a charm!