# How to visualize four-dimensional data?

Tags: plotting

I have following data that I made up for this purpose. In data, let's say first three column is coordinate of center of balls and fourth column is the value I want to plot such that min of fourth column is blue and max of fourth column is red and the rest is between using `TemperatureMap`. I know I may use `ArrayPlot` only for fourth column after partitioning. Or I may use `ListDensityPlot3D`. Another word why there is no `ArrayPlot3D` (instead of square cuboid may be used) in *Mathematica*? Any suggestion? Thanks.

```
data = Append[#, RandomReal[{0, 10}]] & /@ (Append[#, 0] & /@Tuples[Range[1, 6], 2])
Graphics3D[Sphere[#, 0.2] & /@ data[[All, 1 ;; 3]], Axes -> True]
```

Comment: Have you seen `ListDensityPlot3D[]`?

Comment: Also, checking out `Image3D` could be worthwhile.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, I have seen it but it interpolates the data and there is no IntepolationOrder->0 option for that function.

Comment: @kirma I looked up Image3D sorry but that's not what I want. ListDensityPlot3D[] is the closest one but still not exactly.

Comment: Have you seen `BubbleChart3D` ?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(20023)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20023), [(32844)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32844), [(50501)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50501), [(124423)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124423)

Comment: @SimonWoods I was unaware of BubbleChart3D, is this new function?

Comment: No, the documentation says *Introduced in 2008 (7.0) | Updated in 2014 (10.0)*

Comment: BTW, when I use `BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}` balls are getting strange shape, kind of ellipsoid. Is the any way to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
**EDIT:** Corrected to use "TemperatureMap" rather than "Rainbow"

SeedRandom[1]

data = Append[#, RandomReal[{0, 10}]] & /@
   (Append[#, 0] & /@ 
     Tuples[Range[1, 6], 2]);

{min, max} = MinMax[data[[All, 4]]]

(*  {0.118355, 9.77172}  *)

Legended[
 Graphics3D[{
     ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[Last[#], {min, max}]],
     Sphere[Most[#], 0.2]} & /@ data,
  Axes -> True,
  ImageSize -> Large],
 BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {min, max}}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:** Using [`BubbleChart3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart3D.html) as suggested by [`Simon Woods`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods)

```
Legended[
 BubbleChart3D[data,
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, r},
    ColorData["TemperatureMap"][r]]],
 BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {min, max}}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT 3:** Custom color function

```
cf = (Blend[{
      {min, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]},
      {min + 1/3 (max - min), RGBColor[0, 1, 0]},
      {min + 2/3 (max - min), RGBColor[1, 1, 0]},
      {max, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}}, #] &);

Legended[Graphics3D[{cf[Last[#]], Sphere[Most[#], 0.2]} & /@ data, 
  Axes -> True, ImageSize -> Large], BarLegend[{cf, {min, max}}]]
```

[image]

```
Legended[BubbleChart3D[data, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, r}, cf[r]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False], BarLegend[{cf, {min, max}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: @andre - corrected. Thanks.

Comment: You can get the ColorFunction to do the rescaling for you. From the docs: ColorData[{"gradient",{min,max}}] gives a color gradient that ranges from min to max.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I  have one more question. Can we use `ColorFunction -> (Blend[{RGBColor[0, 0, 1], RGBColor[0, 1, 0], 
     RGBColor[1, 1, 0], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}, #] &)`  instead of "TemperatureMap". I want to replace white color with green one. Any suggestion?

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci - see edit. This is described in documentation.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I commented for wrong figure, I would like to use `Graphics3D`

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci - so use the function that I showed.

Comment: `Graphics3D` uses `ColorData` not `ColorFunction` I am totally lost.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you ( I was almost there..)