# ArrayPlot with blended color

Tags: plotting, color, list-manipulation

I have two `ArrayPlot` and I would like to show using one legend. The flowing is works. My question is can we use `ColorFunction -> (Blend[{RGBColor[0, 0, 1], RGBColor[0, 1, 0], 
     RGBColor[1, 1, 0], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}, #] &)`
this instead of `"TemperatureMap"`. I want to replace white color with green one. Any suggestion? Thanks.

```
dataRawIPTG = {{2.18756, 2.17447, 2.17031, 2.16801, 2.31719, 
2.36214}, {2.14151, 2.13749, 2.13819, 2.14531, 2.35749, 
2.40783}, {2.18333, 2.16507, 2.17598, 2.21962, 3.52217, 
3.60957}, {2.21752, 2.14844, 2.15905, 2.76315, 3.70188, 
3.83357}, {2.25902, 2.17451, 2.18496, 2.83573, 3.6727, 
3.82887}, {2.23612, 2.14, 2.17541, 2.76535, 3.61427, 3.80555}};

dataModelIPTG = {{2.10966, 2.10985, 2.11809, 2.22362, 2.30687, 
2.31404}, {2.1349, 2.13515, 2.14581, 2.29441, 2.42998, 
2.44253}, {2.22229, 2.22278, 2.24442, 2.67876, 3.57224, 
3.71233}, {2.22434, 2.22483, 2.24678, 2.69184, 3.6357, 
3.78727}, {2.22436, 2.22485, 2.2468, 2.69197, 3.63634, 
3.78802}, {2.22436, 2.22485, 2.2468, 2.69197, 3.63635, 3.78804}};

minMaxIPTG = MinMax[{dataRawIPTG, dataModelIPTG}];

Framed@Legended[Grid[{{ArrayPlot[dataRawIPTG, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", minMaxIPTG}], 
  Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Range@6}, 
  ImageSize -> 170, DataReversed -> True], 
 ArrayPlot[dataModelIPTG, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", minMaxIPTG}], 
  Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Range@6}, 
  ImageSize -> 170, DataReversed -> True]}}],  BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", minMaxIPTG}, LegendMarkerSize -> 170,   LegendLabel -> 
Placed["Fluorescence (MEPE)", Right, Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &]]]
```

Comment: You'll need `Rescale[]`: `okkesCF = Blend[{RGBColor[0, 0, 1], RGBColor[0, 1, 0], RGBColor[1, 1, 0], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}, Rescale[#, minMaxIPTG]] &;`.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly for `ArrayPlot` but how can I apply it to `Legend`, too.

Comment: Try `BarLegend[{okkesCF, minMaxIPTG}, (* stuff *)]`

Comment: @J.M. It worked. Thank you. I guess I was using  `BarLegend[{"okkesCF", minMaxIPTG}, (* stuff* )]` and it did not work that way.

Comment: @J.M. How can I do the same thing for [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141642/how-to-visualize-four-dimensional-data) . I mean I want to use blended color not `"TemperatureMap"`