# How to color curves in ListPlot3D according to external list?

Tags: plotting, color

I have a list of `{x,y}` generated as

```
Regn = {{-(π/3), -(π/Sqrt[3])}, {-((2 π)/3), 
    0}, {-(π/3), π/Sqrt[3]}, {π/3, π/Sqrt[3]}, {(
    2 π)/3, 0}, {π/3, -(π/Sqrt[3])}, {π/
    3, -(π/Sqrt[3])}, {-(π/3), -(π/Sqrt[3])}};
xylist = 1. Select[RegionMember[Polygon@(Regn)]][
    Join @@ CoordinateBoundsArray[CoordinateBounds@(Regn), Into[50]]];
```

Now, I calculate `f[x,y]`

```
list1 = Table[{xylist[[i, 1]], xylist[[i, 2]], 
    Cos[xylist[[i, 1]]] Cos[xylist[[i, 2]]]}, {i, 1, Length[xylist]}];
```

which looks like

```
ListPlot3D[list1, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotLegends -> False, 
 BoxRatios -> {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]

Finally, I would like to color it according to an external list

```
list2 = Table[{ Sin[xylist[[i, 1]]] Cos[xylist[[i, 2]]]}, {i, 1, 
    Length[xylist]}];
```

I tried the solution [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/listplot3d-how-to-make-the-color-depending-on-a-second-list) but does not give any color, it returns the same plot as above?

```
interp = Interpolation[Transpose[{list1[[All, ;; 2]], list2}]];
colorf = Function[{x, y}, 
   Blend[{{-1, Blue}, {0, Green}, {1, Red}}, interp[x, y]]];
ListPlot3D[list1, ColorFunction -> color,ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotLegends -> False, 
 BoxRatios -> {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, ImageSize -> 200]
```

Comment: forgot the option `ColorFunction ->colorf`  in `ListPlot3D[list1,...]`?

Comment: @kglr, you are right, but I added it in the Notebook just forgot to add in the question. Thanks for the notification!

Answer (score 2):

```
xy = Join @@ CoordinateBoundsArray[CoordinateBounds @ Regn, Into[50]];

lst = N@Join[xy, List /@ (Times @@@ Cos[xy]), List /@ (Times @@@ Cos[4 xy]), 2];
```

Construct an interpolation function using the columns 1, 2 and 4:

```
ClearAll[intF]
intF = Interpolation[{{#, #2}, #4} & @@@ lst]
```

and use it to define a color function:

```
ClearAll[colorF]
colorF = Function[{x, y}, Blend[{{-1, Blue}, {0, Green}, {1, Red}}, intF[x, y]]];
```

Use the option `RegionFunction` to restrict the x-y coordinates of the surface to `Polygon @ Regn`:

```
ListPlot3D[lst[[All, ;; 3]], 
 ColorFunction -> (colorF[#, #2] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 PlotLegends -> False,
 BoxRatios -> 1, 
 ImageSize -> 400, 
 Mesh -> None,
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, RegionMember[Polygon @ Regn][{x, y}]]]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ListPlot3D[Select[RegionMember[Polygon@Regn][#[[;; 2]]] &] @ lst[[All, ;; 3]], 
 ColorFunction -> (colorF[#, #2] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 PlotLegends -> False, 
 BoxRatios -> 1, 
 ImageSize -> 400, 
 Mesh -> None]
```

> same picture

**Note:** For the particular case in OP, we can construct the color function without the need for an interpolation function as

```
ClearAll[colorF2]
colorF2 = Function[{x, y}, 
   Blend[{{-1, Blue}, {0, Green}, {1, Red}}, Cos[4 x] Cos[4 y]];

ListPlot3D[Select[RegionMember[Polygon@Regn][#[[;; 2]]] &]@lst[[All, ;; 3]], 
 ColorFunction -> colorF2, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
 PlotLegends -> False, 
 BoxRatios -> 1, 
 ImageSize -> 400,
 Mesh -> None]
```

> same picture

Comment: That is AWSOME! is it possible to  turn off the interpolation `InterpolationOrder -> 0` in `ListPlot3D` as in `ListDensityPlot`?

Answer (score 0):

I found out  how to do that using `VertexColors` but could not turn off the `InterpolationOrder -> 0`

first, let's restructure the data such that the fourth element of `list1` is the color index

```
list1 = Table[{xylist[[i, 1]], xylist[[i, 2]], 
    Cos[xylist[[i, 1]]] Cos[xylist[[i, 2]]], 
    Cos[4 xylist[[i, 1]]] Cos[4 xylist[[i, 2]]]}, {i, 1, Length[xylist]}];
```

and then define the color function with the desired color scheme and range as follows

```
colorf[z_] := Blend[{Blue, Green, Red}, Rescale[z, {-1, 1}]]
```

Finally,

```
ListPlot3D[list1[[All, ;; 3]], Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> 1, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 VertexColors -> colorf /@ Flatten@list1[[All, 4 ;;]], 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotLegends -> False, 
 BoxRatios -> {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]

Still, one thing I could not do: I would like to turn off the `InterpolationOrder -> 0` like in `DensityPlot`.If someone has an idea please share?

**update**

For the option `InterpolationOrder -> 0` it is valid for `ListPlot3D` but does not give the desired results like in the case of `ListDensityPlot`, especially when the points are largely separated along z-axis, here is a solution for that:

1. `InterpolationOrder -> 0` with `ListPlot3D` gives

`ListPlot3D[list1[[All, ;;3]],Mesh->None,InterpolationOrder->0,BoxRatios->1,Lighting->"Neutral",VertexColors->colorf/@Flatten@list1[[All,4;;]],PlotTheme->"Detailed",PlotLegends->False,BoxRatios->{0.5,0.5,0.5},ImageSize->200]`

[image]

2. using `Graphics3D` gives the desired results

`Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.015],Point[list1[[All, ;;3]],VertexColors->colorf/@Flatten@list1[[All, 4;;]]]},BoxRatios->1,BoxRatios->{0.5,0.5,0.5},ImageSize->200,Boxed->False,Axes->True]`

[image]